# Remove functionality not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am new to jquery  i searched this script in google and customize according to my requirement but i got an issue in that they gave for only one field script but i tried it for five input fields  I am trying to add 5 dynamic fields using jquery 
so adding functionality is working  but when i click remove link its not removing  what am i doing wrong? here my code

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".dynamicinput"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add-more"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col1"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Name *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="PersonalssDetails_firstname" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col2"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Relationship *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field1">Remove</a></div>');
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col3"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Home Telephone*</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field2">Remove</a></div>');
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col4"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Mobile *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field3">Remove</a></div>');
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Work Telephone *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field4">Remove</a></div>');
}
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });


    </script>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Name *</strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="PersonalssDetails_firstname" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name[]"><span>


      </div>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Relationship *</strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship[]"><span>


      </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Home Telephone* </strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone[]"><span>


      </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Mobile * </strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile[]"><span>


      </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Work Telephone * </strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone[]"><span>


      </div>


        </div>
        <div id="dynamicinput" class="dynamicinput">



        </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: 1. your html is wrong; you have unclosed span tags. 2. your js is looking for a button, but where is your button in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UE0wAS2plFPyUlWgf0lO)

**Description**
You are only attaching the event handler to elements with a class of `.remove_field` but you have it dynamically adding `.remove_field\d` IE with a digit.

You are calling `$(this).parent('div').remove();` but this only looks 1 element above your current element using `closest` resolves this

The below JavaScript resolves this.

**JS**

```
$(wrapper).on("click", "[class^=remove_field]", function(e) { //user click on remove text
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this);
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
  x--;
})
```

---

### jQuery Documentation

`parent()`

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the parent() method traverses to the **immediate parent** of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

`closest()`

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.
>
> ---

### StackOverflow Demo

```js
// Code goes here
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed

$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrapper = $(".dynamicinput"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add-more"); //Add button ID

  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col1"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Name *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="PersonalssDetails_firstname" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col2"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Relationship *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field1">Remove</a></div>');
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col3"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Home Telephone*</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field2">Remove</a></div>');
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col4"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Mobile *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field3">Remove</a></div>');
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Work Telephone *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field4">Remove</a></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", "[class^=remove_field]", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).parent('div'));
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
        <strong>Name *</strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="PersonalssDetails_firstname" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name[]" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
        <strong>Relationship *</strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship[]" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
        <strong>Home Telephone* </strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone[]" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
        <strong>Mobile * </strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile[]" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
        <strong>Work Telephone * </strong>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone[]" />
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dynamicinput" class="dynamicinput"></div>
  <input type="button" class="add-more" value="add" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's closest function for finding parent element:

```
 $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).closest('div.col-md-4').remove();  // Just used col-md-4 class as selector, but you can specify more specific one.
            x--;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrjs6dhx/2/)

Wrap your inputs in a div to make it easier to remove and then call last().remove on it. here is a working example of your code

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".dynamicinput"); //Fields wrapper


    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(".add_button").click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append("<div class='extra-inputs'>");

            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col1"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Name *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="PersonalssDetails_firstname" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Name[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col2"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Relationship *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Relationship[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field1">Remove</a></div>');
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col3"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Home Telephone*</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_HomeTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field2">Remove</a></div>');
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col4"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Mobile *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_Mobile[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field3">Remove</a></div>');
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 col5"><div class="form-group"><label for="exampleInputEmail1"><strong>Work Telephone *</strong></label><input type="text" class="form-control textwidth" id="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" class="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone" name="AssignedEmergencyContacts_WorkTelephone[]"><span><a href="#" class="remove_field4">Remove</a></div>');
            $(wrapper).append("</div>");
         }
    });

    $(".remove_button").on("click", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        $(wrapper).last("extra-inputs").remove()
        x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi! Your jsfiddle example doesn't work. Would you please correct it, so that it works when we try it out?